# How to pass an object by @Html.ActionLink or any other Html helper meethod from View to Controller Action?

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an object inside the `View` which I want to pass to controller's action.

This object is not in database so(It was created in another action and passed to this `View`) I want to pass whole object using @Html methods(create a button and pass it when it is clicked to the Action).

For example I have `Type object` variable in the view. How to pass it(the object) by clicking a button to action. I would like to use `@Html.*` methods not Java Script.

Controller Name: `MyController`

```
 public ActionResult MyAction(Type ReceivedObject) { 
     return View(); 
 }
```

---

### EDIT

So I don't know what to do anymore.

Here I created a list of elements which are copies of elements in the database(there are 2 surveys in database). I pass them to the `_Survey1.cshtml` view

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _Survey1(int id) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PASSED ID: " + id);
            Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
            //Passing a Tuple to Partial View
            List<Survey> localSurveysCopy = new List<Survey>();
            foreach (Survey survey in db.Surveys) {
                localSurveysCopy.Add(new Survey(survey));
            }
            var tuple = new Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>(person, localSurveysCopy) { };
            return PartialView(tuple);
        }
```

Those elements are modified in the `_Survey1.cshtml` view. The user clicks radiobuttons like here:

[image]

There is editor helper for every question in survey which defines that radiobutton saves answer in `AnswerText` property of `Question`:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Question
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    <h3> @Model.QuestionText </h3>
    @foreach (var a in Model.Answers) {
        <p>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.SelectedAnswer, a.Id)  @a.AnswerText
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

And this is the `_Survey1` view which renders surveys:

```
@using WebApplication2.Models
@model   System.Tuple<Person, List<Survey>>

<hr />
<h1>Surveys</h1>

<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />

@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var survey in Model.Item2) {
    using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <h2>Survey @(i)</h2>
        <p />
        @Html.EditorFor(x => survey.Questions)

   // <p>@Html.ActionLink("Call Cell Phone", "SubmitSurvey", new {survey = survey}, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>

    }
    i++;
    <hr style="background-color:rgb(126, 126, 126);height: 5px" />
}
<hr />
```

Here is the method I want to pass part of a model to, both actions are in the same controller.

```
    public ActionResult SubmitSurvey(Person id, List<Survey> listOfSurveys) {
        //BECAUSE OF ID's of copied Surveys and questions and answers in the 
        // listOfSurveys are the same  as Id's of original Questions
        // in database I want to bind Selected Answers with the Persons here 
        //that is why I need this list
        return View();
    }
```

Passing `Person id` is easy but how to pass this List?

And here is how `Survey`, `Question` and `Answer` look:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {


    public class Survey {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { set; get; }

        public Survey() { }
        public Survey(Survey survey) {
            Id = survey.Id;
            Questions = new List<Question>();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SURVEY " + survey.Questions == null);
           foreach (Question question in survey.Questions) {
                Questions.Add(new Question(question));
            }
        }
    }
    public class Question {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string QuestionText { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
        public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
        public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; } //this field is SET after clicking SAVE button

        public Question() { }

        public Question(Question question) {
            Id = question.Id;
            QuestionText = question.QuestionText;
            Answers = question.Answers;
            Survey = question.Survey;
            SelectedAnswer = "";
        }
    }
    public class Answer {C:\Users\R\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Models\Survey.cs
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string AnswerText { set; get; }
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the `Person` who remembers which answers were chosen so (many to many relationship `Answer<---> Person`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can pass this object as route parameter

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Or at least you can't in the way you're thinking.

First, this has nothing to do with the helpers. The helpers just generate HTML, so they're bound by the constraints of HTML. Second, the URL you need to generate is itself bound by the constraints of HTTP. If you're talking about doing a GET request (your standard run of the mill anchor link in HTML), then the only way to pass data is via the query string. That's the `?foo=bar&bar=baz` jazz you see in URLs sometimes. The query string only supports simple name-value pairs. There's no way to pass a full object as a single paramater, though you could pass each property of that object individually. The modelbinder in MVC is smart enough to take the individual items of the query string and join them back into the class they belong to if it can match them up. For example, assume you have a class like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}
```

And an action like:

```
public ActionResult Foo(Foo model)
{
    ...
}
```

You could generate a link that would work via:

```
@Html.ActionLink("This is a foo.", "Foo", new { Bar = "Bar", Baz = 1 })
```

The modelbinder would recognize that it had values for `Bar` and `Baz` in the query string and use that to create an instance of `Foo` with those values.

If you have a POST request, which you can only get by using an HTML form with `method` set to "post", then you can include the properties of the class in a similar way, only now, they'll be actual HTML inputs instead of passed directly in the query string. For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Foo")) {
    <input type="hidden" name="Bar" value="Bar" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Baz" value="1" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Again, the modelbinder will match up the property names and construct an instance of the class with those values. However, again, you cannot simply pass an object, but only the properties of that object individually. Even with a POST, HTML alone is only capable of submitting an `x-www-form-urlencoded` post body, which is simply the fancy name for the style of the query string you see in a GET request.

To post an actual object, you'd have to use some data interchange format such as JSON or XML. And, that can only be done with the aid of JavaScript, which you explicitly don't want.

Comment: I am devastated(I deal with it for almost a week now). Could you please look at the edit to my post? I will answer every question. Please help.

Comment: Generally the idea was to hold List of chosen Answers and don't create  Survey for every user in database just hold "Original" survey with their set of Questions and Answers in database and remember which Answers are binded to which `Person`. That's why I create copy in controller of those objects in database, because if 2 or more people would submit survey at the same time on different machines their radio buttons would work on the Same OBJECT -> Survey. So I make them locally and then they will by deleted by trash collector.

Comment: I will start bounty when I can and offer as much rep as it needs I just don't know how should I fix this.

Comment: The problem is you're trying to represent distinct things as the same thing. A survey question is a fundamentally different thing that a particular user's answer to that survey question. I would personally create a new entity, something like `AnsweredQuestion` which attaches to the `Person` and holds a relationship between a particular answer the user chose and the question it belonged to. You might even be better off condensing it down even more such that you actually record the question and answer text at the time the user answered it, as these could potentially change over time.

Comment: But how bind RadioButton click to change something in `AnsweredQuestion`. I think this AnswerQuestion should look like 
`public class AnsweredQuestion{public Person Person{get;set;}; public Question Question{get;set;}; public Answer Answer {get;set}}`. If you could say something more about please, but either way thank you very much. In different words: how to bind radio button or how to pass selected answers to the controller.

Comment: Here he passes http://www.techiesweb.net/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc/ full model an object of type `Evaluation`  by  `@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Questions)
    <input type="submit" />` to the controller's action: `[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Index(Evaluation model)` how is he doing it?

Comment: Umm, no. He has a form with individual fields for each property on the model. If the `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Questions)` part is throwing you, that's shorthand. Razor will generate fields to satisfy the class of what's passed in tye expression, but you'll still have a field for each property for each question instance.